# Is there a way to take database dump from postgresql console?

Tags: postgresql, psql, database-backups

I know, we can take database dump using command line utility `pg_dump` but I wanted to know if we can take sql dump from `psql` console.

Answer (score 1):

PGOPTIONS="-c statement_timeout=5000000" pg_dump -x -O -U dbusername dbname > export.dump

then

psql dbname -f export.dump

Answer (score 0):

You can't do full exports, but you can do partial dumps of data.

You can export the results of queries or full tables via the `\copy` command.  This is very similar to the the `COPY` SQL statement except that the file only needs to be accessible to the user running psql instead of accessible to the database server.

The `\copy` command can do both exports and imports so you can use it to copy information between databases.  It doesn't do the DDL (create table etc).

[psql \copy command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html)

[COPY command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html)